# Check multiple tables in one single query

Tags: mysql, join, select

I want to `SELECT` data from my MySQL using PHP but the `WHERE` clause can be kind of confusing.

Basically i want to select the appointments that are coming up, then checking if the business is wanting to send out reminders, then checking if the user wants to receive reminders. But I want to do all that in one query.

Here are my tables:

```
appointments
    - appointment_date
    - appointment_time
    - business_id
    - user_id

businesses
    - reminders_enabled

users
    - reminders_enabled
```

Here are the steps of what I want to do before I select the right data:

1. `SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE DATE(appointment_date) = CURDATE() AND appointment_time is within the next 1 hour`
2. From the data selected above from step #1, I want to filter it. I want to `SELECT * FROM businesses WHERE business_id = business_id_from_step_1 AND reminders_enabled = 1`
3. Then I want to filter it even more. If results are found after step 2, do another select: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = user_id_from_step_1 AND reminders_enabled = 1`

That's it after that. How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The `JOIN`s do the filtering as you describe in your steps 1-3:

```
SELECT *
FROM appointments a
JOIN businesses b ON b.business_id = a.business_id AND b.reminders_enabled = 1
JOIN users u ON u.user_id = a.user_id AND u.reminders_enabled = 1
WHERE DATE(a.appointment_date) = CURDATE() AND 
      a.appointment_time BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! But what if I replace `AND b.reminders_enabled = 1` with `AND (b.email_reminders = 1 OR b.text_reminders = 1)` and then I replace `AND (u.email_reminders = 1 OR u.text_reminders = 1)`, the results come back but it only shows `b.email_reminders` and `b.text_reminders`. How can I make it show `b` and `u`?

Comment: Never mind, I replaced the `SELECT *` with `SELECT b.email_reminder AS bus_email_reminder, b.text_reminder AS bus_text_reminder, u.email_reminder AS user_email_reminder, u.text_reminder AS user_text_reminder`

Comment: @pixie123 sorry I wasn't around to respond to your comment but glad you sorted it out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM appointments 
      WHERE DATE(appointment_date) = CURDATE()
      AND appointment_time BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
      AND business_id in (SELECT business_id FROM businesses WHERE reminders_enabled=1)
      AND user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE reminders_enabled=1)
```